# One to many/inverse relationship - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This seems simple enough but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have the below Models

**City** -> *HasMany* **Locations**

**Locations** -> *HasMany* **Restaurants**

**Restaurants** -> *BelongsTo* **Locations**

This means that **Restaurant** is linked to **City** via **Locations**

Now I want to find **Restaurants** in a particular **City** based the **Location** provided but not restricted to just that location rather the **City**.

The values provided are the **City** name and **Location** name.
So I can get the `city_id` and `location_id`

```
// this will get a city with all locations
$city = City::with('locations')->where('value', $c)->first();
$city_id = $city->id;

// this will get the location id
$location = Location::where('value', $l)->first();
$location_id = $location->id;
```

So my `$restaurants` query should find all restaurants where the `location` is part of the `location` of `$city`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a **HasManyThrough** relationship like this -

```
class City extends Model
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Location');
    }
    public function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Restaurant', 'App\Location');
    }
}

class Location extends Model
{
    public function City()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
    public function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Restaurant');
    }
}
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
    }
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
    }
}
```

> Check out the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: How will my query look like?

Assuming `Restaurants` belongs to `City` this would be the query I would use;

`$restaurants = Restaurant::with('restaurantClass')->where('city_id', $city_id)->get();`

Comment: If you want to get all the restaurants in a city you will need to write a scope for that. You can access the city that a restaurant belongs to like this --> $restaurant->city;

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: well are you trying to find all the restaurants given a particular city?

Comment: Yes, I need a query to find all restaurants in a particular city based on the location provided

Comment: so you can do something like this.. $city->whereLocationId($location_id)->restaurants

Comment: How can i apply `where` to the `restaurants` fetched though?

Comment: You can do something like **$city->whereLocationId($location_id)->restaurants()->where('some_db_column', '=', $some_value)->get()**